# display selected videoframe on Qt via GStreamer

Tags: c++, qt, gstreamer

I need to display selected video frame in the Qt application(e.g. first frame of video, second frame of video e.t.c.). Index of frame is chosen by QT buttons or slider.

I used this code to connect GStreamer pipeline with QtWidget https://gstreamer.freedesktop.org/documentation/video/gstvideooverlay.html?gi-language=c#gstvideooverlay-and-qt, so I can display video in application. I use "playbin" pipeline. I can start and pause video via Qt button event.

I used code from this page https://gstreamer.freedesktop.org/documentation/application-development/advanced/queryevents.html?gi-language=c#events-seeking-and-more to set video stream time/frame, but I can do this only in GST_STATE_PLAYING. I need to do this in GST_STATE_PAUSED.

I'm new in Qt and GStreamer, can someone describe for me how to do that?

Answer (score 0):

You need to wait for the state change to complete; in this case the GST_STATE_PAUSED. The state changes can be asynchronous meaning that the state transition might not be complete immediately after calling the state setting function. In order to wait until the state change is completed you can use `gst_element_get_state` and that will allow you to perform the seek operation properly.

```c
  // Run the pipeline
  GstStateChangeReturn sret = gst_element_set_state (pipeline,
      GST_STATE_PAUSED);
  if (sret == GST_STATE_CHANGE_FAILURE) {
    gst_element_set_state (pipeline, GST_STATE_NULL);
    gst_object_unref (pipeline);
    // Exit application
    QTimer::singleShot(0, QApplication::activeWindow(), SLOT(quit()));
  }

  // Wait for the state change to complete
  GstState state;
  gst_element_get_state(pipeline, &state, NULL, GST_CLOCK_TIME_NONE);
  if (GST_STATE_PAUSED == state) {
      g_printerr("Unable to set state to GST_STATE_PAUSED state.\n");
      gst_object_unref(pipeline);
      // Exit application
      QTimer::singleShot(0, QApplication::activeWindow(), SLOT(quit()));
  }
```